# Sum of values of child columns

Tags: laravel

I have title model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Title extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public function solds()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Sold', 'title_id');
    }
}
```

In my controller

```
    public function index()
    {
        $titles = Title::with(['solds'])->get();
        return Inertia::render('Product/Index',[
            'titles' => $titles,
        ]);
    }
```

my migrations

```
Schema::create('solds', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->bigInteger('title_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->decimal('price_usd');
            $table->decimal('price_gel');
            $table->decimal('quantity');
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('title_id')->references('id')->on('titles')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
Schema::create('titles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('code')->unique();
            $table->string('title')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

How can I get sum of quantity in my controller ?
i want to get these row

ID     Code    Title   Sum of Quantity of child

Sorry for my bad English

I've tried a lot of google suggestions, but I can't solved my problesm

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use an [aggregate function](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions) to get this info:

```php
$titles = Title::with('solds')->withSum('solds', 'quantity')->get();
```

Then in your view you can access `$title->solds_sum_quantity`

---

Or, if you'd prefer, you already have `$title->solds` as a collection, so you can just use [the `Collection::sum()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-sum) like  `$title->solds->sum("quantity")` without any changes to your controller code.